# How do you test a service in spring mvc with mockito, rxjava2 using an io scheduler?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit4, rx-java2

I'm attempting to test a service method that makes use of rxjava2, flatmap and the io scheduler. The test does not seem to be calling any of the mocked methods using mockito despite appearing to run.  The observable never returns an object.

How do you test spring services with multithreaded rxjava2 code?

Here is the method in the service I'm testing

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public io.reactivex.Observable<EntryStatistic> compute(final User user, final int startYear, final int endYear) {
    final GregorianCalendar calendarg = new GregorianCalendar();

    if (endYear < startYear)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("endYear");
    if (endYear < 2003)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("endYear");
    if (startYear < 2003)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("startYear");

    return io.reactivex.Observable.range(startYear, endYear - startYear + 1)
            .flatMap(new Function<Integer, ObservableSource<EntryStatistic>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<EntryStatistic> apply(final Integer yr) throws Exception {
                    return io.reactivex.Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<EntryStatistic>() {
                        @Override
                        public EntryStatistic call() throws Exception {

                            log.debug("testing with year: " + yr + " user: " + user.getUsername() );
                            EntryStatistic es = entryStatisticRepository.findByUserAndYear(user, yr);
                            final long count = entryRepository.calendarCount(yr, user.getUsername());

                            if (es == null) {
                                log.trace("Creating new entry statistic");
                                es = new EntryStatistic();
                                es.setUser(user);
                            }

                            es.setCount(count);
                            es.setYear(yr);
                            es.setModified(calendarg.getTime());

                            log.trace("save and flush time");
                            return entryStatisticRepository.saveAndFlush(es);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

Here is the test code:

```
@Test
public void computeSingle() {
    when(entryStatisticRepository.findByUserAndYear(user, TEST_YEAR + 1)).thenReturn(entryStatistic);
    when(user.getUsername()).thenReturn(TEST_USER);
    when(entryRepository.calendarCount(TEST_YEAR, TEST_USER)).thenReturn(1L);
    when(entryStatistic.getUser()).thenReturn(user);
    when(entryStatistic.getCount()).thenReturn(1L);
    when(entryStatistic.getYear()).thenReturn(TEST_YEAR);
    when(entryStatisticRepository.saveAndFlush(entryStatistic)).thenReturn(entryStatistic);

    TestObserver<EntryStatistic> testObserver = entryStatisticService.compute(user, TEST_YEAR, TEST_YEAR )
            .test();

    testObserver.awaitTerminalEvent();
    testObserver
        .assertNoErrors()
        .assertValue(new Predicate<EntryStatistic>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(final EntryStatistic entryStatistic) throws Exception {
                return entryStatistic.getCount() == 1L ;
            }
        });

    verify(entryStatisticRepository, atLeastOnce()).findByUserAndYear(user, TEST_YEAR);
    verify(entryRepository, atLeastOnce()).calendarCount(TEST_YEAR, TEST_USER);
}
```

Finally, here is the attempt I did to force a single threaded scheduler for the code as a junit rule.

```
public class TrampolineSchedulerRule implements TestRule {

@Override
public Statement apply(final Statement base, Description d) {
  return new Statement() {
    @Override
    public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(new Function<Scheduler, Scheduler>() {
            @Override
            public Scheduler apply(final Scheduler scheduler) throws Exception {
                return Schedulers.trampoline();
            }
        });
        RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(new Function<Scheduler, Scheduler>() {
                         @Override
                         public Scheduler apply(final Scheduler scheduler) throws Exception {
                             return Schedulers.trampoline();
                         }
                     });
        RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler(new Function<Scheduler, Scheduler>() {
                                      @Override
                                      public Scheduler apply(final Scheduler scheduler) throws Exception {
                                          return Schedulers.trampoline();
                                      }
                                  });


      try {
        base.evaluate();
      } finally {
        RxJavaPlugins.reset();
      }
    }
  };
}
}
```

The issue is that no object is returned. I see the error

> java.lang.AssertionError: No values (latch = 0, values = 0, errors =
>   0, completions = 1)

Comment: Very strange, that range.flatMap should produce one item. Can you set a breakpoint in the flatMap's function and inside the inner fromCallable to see if they execute or not?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with mock setup, since you run with both `startYear` and `endYear` equal to `TEST_YEAR` the only `yr` value that will be executed is equal to `TEST_YEAR` but you setup `when(entryStatisticRepository.findByUserAndYear(user, TEST_YEAR + 1))`. I have tried your code without mocks and test passes fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with how mocks are setup. This mocked call

```
 when(entryStatisticRepository.saveAndFlush(entryStatistic)).thenReturn(entryStatistic);
```

expects `entryStatistic` object to be passed to `saveAndFlush`, but actually new `EntryStatistic` object is passed to `saveAndFlush` and desired mock value is not returned. That means that null value is returned from `Callable`. Since `null` values can not be emitted in `rx-java2` that leads to no values being emitted by `flatMap` and you receive immediate completion with no values.

The test can be fixed by removing plus one in (as range will only emit one value equal to TEST_YEAR)

```
when(entryStatisticRepository.findByUserAndYear(user, TEST_YEAR+1)).thenReturn(entryStatistic);
```

One interesting question is why `flatMap` returns no items and successful completion for

```
Observable.range(0, 10).flatMap(i -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> null))
```

and completes with error for

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> null)
```

and also completes with error for

```
Observable.range(0, 10).flatMap(i -> Observable.error(new RuntimeException()))
```

I guess this is just how rx developers decided to handle nulls in `flatMap`, here we are working with something that is not supposed to be used anyway (EDIT: confirmed to be a bug, see comment)

Comment: as confirmed by @akarnokd in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304226/null-handling-in-rx-java2-flatmap/ there is a bug in rx-java2. When it is fixed the original test will finish with onError due to null returned by callable.