# Null handling in rx-java2 flatMap

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

As explained in the [docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#nulls) RxJava 2.x no longer accepts null values. So it is not surprising that both of the following two lines terminate with `onError` called:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> null);
Observable.just(1).flatMap(i -> Observable.error(new RuntimeException()));
```

what is unclear is why

```
Observable.just(1).flatMap(i -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> null))
```

terminates with success and no items emitted. It seams reasonable to expect for it behave in the same fashion as `Observable.error`

I can see in source code of rx-java 2.1.2

```
 public final <R> Observable<R> flatMap(...) {
    if (this instanceof ScalarCallable) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T v = ((ScalarCallable<T>)this).call();
        if (v == null) {
            return empty();
        }
        ...
 }
```

which explains why it is happening in terms of code, but I still have two questions:

1) Is this is an intended behavior or a bug?

2) If intended, is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with the `Observable.fromCallable` and will be fixed with [PR 5517](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/5517).

If, for some reason you can't avoid a null return in this setup, you can apply `hide()` to workaround this bug:

```
Observable.just(1).flatMap(i -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> null).hide())
```

or help RxJava throw:

```
Observable.just(1)
    .flatMap(i -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> 
         java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(apiReturningNull()))
    )
```